# Proper way to select hundreds of arbitrary rows without having individual queries for each without table value parameters

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

Lets say I have a table "Persons" and each person has a first name, a middle name, and a last name.
I have a text file with hundreds of persons, and I need to get the database row of each person from the database.  I have to do this within a limited time, it can't take more than a few seconds.

In general, assume I have a big random list of values and cannot easily do a WHERE clause to grab all of them, as they are evenly spread across the data and there are millions of rows.

Is there a "good" way to do this in various SQL servers? The only two ways I know are:

- Run each query one by one, with a network trip for each query
- Combine every query into one big string and run that query.

The first one ends up being very slow, and the second one works but makes it difficult to use parameters as you end up having to do `@PARAM1`, `@PARAM2`, and so on into infinity. It ends up running into parameter limits as well, once you're selecting more than a thousand or so rows (with each row having no single number/identity key)

For context, this is for SQL Server/C#, but I'd like to know if there is a more general/cross platform solution as well.

Some way to do updates would be useful as well, if that would be different than a select statement.

I understand that table value parameters are a thing, but I cannot add extra values or definitions to the SQL Server to use them for the queries I am trying to run, I can only control what is going on in my program.

Comment: Your best bet would be to do a bulk insert of the data from text file into a temporary table. Then you can write an efficient query across tables. There are plenty of resources out there on how to bulk load data into sql server like [SqlBulkCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy) and [BULK INSERT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql)

Comment: Please provide example data to illustrate what you are referring to. Its not possible to provide advice without knowing the specifics of how you are identifying the individuals to query.

Comment: A query, including a table variable, including hundreds of parametrized insert statements generated in a loop and at the same time of generation, name/value of the parameters stored in a dictionary, including a select statement joining the persons table and the table variable to get the result. Then to run the query, pass the parameters which you already have in dictionary to the command.

Comment: In general, if performance is very important, you need TVP and if it's not available it means the performance risk is accepted.

Comment: In response to Dale, this isn't a specific example. In the past I've run into this issue and resolved it in a number of ways, but I am curious to know if there is a "proper" and accepted way.

I'm mostly curious here about the ability to write whatever process works best into a function so I can "forget it" in the future and not have to worry about bulk inserts being very slow.  Going out of my way to define a table value every time I have a lot of records to insert , select, or update isn't going to work in the long term for me.

Answer (score 1):

1. filled an array with the data from your text file.
2. Created a DataTable to hold the returned rows.
3. Created a Connection and Command then added Parameters to the Command.

Notice that the command and parameters are created only once outside the loop. Only the values are changed inside the loop. This allows Sql Server to reuse the plan for the command.

I filled a grid just to show what was returned. You would probably want to put your stop watch before this line since displaying the data is a slow process.

```
    private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("persons.txt");
        Person[] persons = new Person[lines.Length];
        int index = 0;
        foreach (string s in lines)
        {
            string[] arr = s.Split(',');
            persons[index] = new Person(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]);
        }
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.CoffeeConnection))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * From Person Where FirstName = @FName And MiddleName = @MName And LastName = @LName;", cn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@FName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@MName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("LName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
            cn.Open();
            foreach (Person p in persons)
            {
                cmd.Parameters["@FName"].Value = p.firstName;
                cmd.Parameters["@MName"].Value = p.middleName;
                cmd.Parameters["@LName"].Value = p.lastName;
                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
```